# bash alias expantion

Tags: bash, shell, command-line

Is there a way to "expand" a bash alias on the command-line and get the command behind it?
So it for instance would turn ls into;

```
ls --color=auto
```

I keep getting into situations when my aliases does almost what I want to do, but not exactly...

Is this possible all suggestions or answers appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$ alias alias_name
```

It will show you the expansion of the given alias name

Answer (score 1):

And a much more complex way, which is suitable for echoing:

```
$ cut -d = -f1 --complement< <(alias alias_name) | tr '"'"'" ' '
```

So, in a function like

```
exp() { 
  cmd=$1 
  shift 
  echo $(cut -d = -f1 --complement< <(alias $cmd) | tr '"'"'" ' ') $@
}
```

would result in echoing the command as it would be issued to the shell, after all expansions are in place.

This might be useful for debugging.

```
$ exp ll .*
ls -l --color=tty . .. .bash_history .bash_logout .bash_profile .bashrc .lesshst
```